# dompdf stream pdf in browser using localhost, but not in network ip

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, pdf, dompdf

i need to know why dompdf doesn't stream a pdf in browser before download on network ip like 192.168.1.77 , but it works on localhost.

when using network ip, it just immediately download the file , it won't show pdf preview in browser

i'm using dompdf version 0.6.2
this is my code

```
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    ob_start();

    $this->load->view('report_me',array_merge($this->sesi,$this->session->userdata('printdata')));
    // header('Pragma','public');
    $html = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    // $this->session->unset_userdata('printdata');
// $dompdf->set_option('setIsHtml5ParserEnabled', true);


    $dompdf->load_html($html);

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
// $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'potrait');

// Render the HTML as PDF
    $dompdf->render();
    $canvas = $dompdf->get_canvas();
    $font = Font_Metrics::get_font("helvetica", "bold");
    $canvas->page_text(44, 760, "Page {PAGE_NUM} of {PAGE_COUNT}", $font, 8, array(0,0,0));

//ERASE SESSION

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
    $dts = date('Y-m-d');
    // $dompdf->output();
    // $dompdf->stream();
    $dompdf->stream('inv_'.$this->Master_model->getInvoiceNumber().'_'.$dts.'.pdf',array('Attachment'=>0));
```

i had enabling the

> ENABLE_REMOTE

to TRUE

Seems like i'm the only one that face the problem, hope someone can help me through this..

Comment: So, you're accessing the same machine but the result varies depending on whether or not you use the IP address? Maybe a browser issue? Have you tried a different browser?

Answer (score 2):

Encountered a similar problem on Laravel and tried adding headers. Doesn't work.

I added `exit;` after `stream()` and it started displaying. I am guessing the framework may be doing something after `stream()` causing headers to revert to `text/html`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the header at the top:

```
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
```

This should display it in the browser.

If you want it to download set the header like this:

```
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='path/to/file/name.pdf');
```

- this can be set after you have created the pdf and saved it somewhere
- NB: path/to/file/name.pdf is on the server not on your local machine

Comment: thanks for your reply @Samantha , but it's still doesn't work for me.

Comment: how are you calling the php file? for localhost is it - http://localhost/path/to/dompdffile.php and for remote is it http://192.168.1.77/path/to/dompdffile.php

Comment: i'm using codeigniter , which is called by base_url()."to/the/file/"

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove some spaces or line breaks between `html` `head` `body` starting and closing tags. Like this `<html><head>` `</head><body>` `</body><html>`.

Also remove `thead` `tbody` `tfoot` tags from your html (sometimes this is not necessary, but in mycase I needed to remove).

And if you are calling the DOM class multiple times. Change the assigned variables (dont let them to be same variable which is in my case was `$pdf = new DOMPDF`. In second class call I was using same variable. I changed it to `$pdf2`)

It has taken from here; https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/902#issuecomment-197655763