# Dompdf works locally but not online

Tags: php, dompdf

I have problems with dompdf, it works perfectly on localhost, but absolutely not online :

The pdf isn't generated but is displayed on the browser : my code :

```
<?php ob_start();?>
//My code

<?php $html = ob_get_clean();

require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
?>
<?php

// reference the Dompdf namespace

use Dompdf\Dompdf;

// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml($html);

 // (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream(); ?>


Votre paiement a bien été pris en compte. 

<?php 

$output = $dompdf->output();
file_put_contents("factures/".$nbr.".pdf", $output);

 ?>
```

Comment: So the `file_put_contents` is the only thing that’s not working? Then that is most likely an issue of write permissions on the file system level.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Do you know how to solve the problem?

Comment: By giving write permission to the location in question to the user the web server, resp. PHP, is executed under … If you have no idea, then best ask your server admin.

Comment: Hi , check it by creating the main folder "factures" manually

Comment: check whether the pdf file is getting generated and saved into factures folder. If it is not saving, try to upload a dummy file into factures folder manually, if it is failing to upload, it means there is a permissions issue. you need to change that permissions

Comment: Thanks everyone, the problem is not coming from the permissions ; I just changed the permissions to 777 in the file "factures" and it stills displays on the browser instead of downloading.

Comment: Anyone has an idea?

Comment: check my answer at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36597866/dompdf-stream-pdf-in-browser-using-localhost-but-not-in-network-ip/61410770#61410770